# What are the best examples of how American women spoke in the 1940s?

Tags: american-english, vernacular

I'm struggling to figure out what the best examples of American 1940s speech would be, especially for women.

Movies from the 40s often suffer from Mid-Atlantic accents. Much of the media of the day was sanitized, so it may make the speech cleaner than it actually was, particularly with female characters?

What today is considered a good example for teaching how people spoke in the 40s?

Comment: What do you mean “suffer from”?

Comment: @Jim Those accents are not natural, but stage voices. That makes them far from ideal sources.

Comment: Requests for resources are better dealt with on meta: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kris Thank you, Kris. I'll repost the question there.

Comment: Try looking for home movies from that time period.